# MS Edge HTML5 Video height incorrect and adding alot of white padding

Tags: css, html, video, microsoft-edge

This is working fine in all other browsers except in Edge . The issue is that the video has way too much height in MS Edge thus adding white space above and beneath it.

I have also added height and width attributes but they didnt make a difference.
Here is Chrome/Firefox:

[image]

Here is Edge:

[image]

Its worth mentioning that it reduces in height if I make the browser smaller in height.

HTML

```
<video controls loop muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="employment-law.mp4">
    <source type="video/ogg" src="employment-law.ogv">
    <source type="video/webm" src="employment-law.webm">
</video>
```

CSS:

```
.module-sample-video {
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
}

video {
   width:100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   max-height: 100px;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I feel there is more to this than what is being presented. Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, yes I wasnt sure what else to include or if it was relevant to include other CSS/HTML around it, but in this case, it really didnt feel like it. I am going to edit my question now to add the link itself which is more verifiyable than anything... https://www.obseckio.com/

Comment: What you include is anything that is necessary to duplicate your issue. In your case that doesn't have to be a whole web page. Linking offsite helps now, but it does not help those in the future who might benefit from seeing a working example of the problem before seeing the solution.

Comment: ok, just working on a JSFiddle

Comment: Create a Stack Snippet instead of a JSFiddle. That way users don't need to leave the site.

Comment: The webpage you have posted had this problem for a couple of minutes, but when I refreshed it, the problem went away - are you actively fixing it in the meantime?

Comment: I noticed the issue was when `min-height:100%` was applied to the `<video>` element, causing it to be the height of the viewport. Normally this is not what you would expect from a percentage height - typically a height has to be set on a parent element. As I could not figure out an explanation as to why percentage heights were doing this in this instance I did not submit an answer. I did notice that they stylesheet was being loaded twice and there are a lot of atypical practices being applied, i.e. float all divs, buttons etc. by default.

Comment: Can you please inform us, Why there are 2 CSS blocks for video tag? If possible for you, than you can try to keep only 1 block of CSS for video tag. Try to remove min-height:100% may help to fix your issue for MS Edge. I tested with chrome, Firefox. It does not affect the output if there is no min-height.